# Systems that implement SAGA

Tags: microservices, saga

Do you know some tool, or systems, or framework, or middleware that provide an implementation for the SAGA pattern for transactions?

I found [eventuate](https://github.com/eventuate-tram/eventuate-tram-sagas), are you aware of others?

Thank you in advance

Comment: May be you can try AXON sagas

Answer (score 0):

You can try NServiceBus: https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/sagas/

One of the core features in NServiceBus is Sagas among others.

(Disclaimer: I work for Particular and am an NServiceBus user for many years)